# Pressing space does weird things

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I've made a simple game in flex. You control falling blocks and your goal is to eliminate viruses. It's almost a copy of the 90s game dr Mario. I've made it so you control blocks with the arrow keys and you spin the block with space. Everything works fine as it should when playing. However when i switch to another program and the application is out of focus and i get back to the game, whenever i press space the game restarts. It's like it calls a function that reinitializes the game and resets all the variables to the start values.
The game is made with several NavigationContent components that acts like scenes. The game doesn't go back to the start screen when i press space, it just resets the game. Wich is really weird.
Are there any default method that is called that causes this behavior? Anyone have a clue?

EDIT: The issue arises - as it seems - exclusively when i tie a function to the space key (keyCode 32). I solved the issue by rebinding the key to "CTRL". But still it would be great to know what's up with the SPACE key. The game works fine with space if i use Internet Explorer. Other browsers doesn't work with the space key. It's the same issue with all of them.

EDIT: This is how the event listener looks:

this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveBlocksKeyboardEvent);

Even if i comment out all the code in the moveBlocksKeyboardEvent method the game still restarts. It's exclusively when hitting the SPACE-key. If i hold down the key the blocks spin. It's when i release the space button the game restarts. As if it's some reinitialization method tied to the KEY_UP event or something.

Comment: Is this a mobile game?  OR a desktop game?  Or a browser based game?  Is the space bar key used in gameplay somehow?  IF so, how.  Without a review of code, it is tough to even know where to start.

Comment: There's no magical KEY_UP listener that listens for the SPACE key. The most logical thing is that you have added this somewhere in your code :) One way to confirm: Did the SPACE key do anything when you assigned the listener to the CTRL key. Have you defined a method to reset the game? If so comment that method out, then when it compiles it will generate an error so you can verify all the places where the reset function is getting used...

Answer (score 0):

This type of behaviour is often tied to a null or undefined value, causing a nonsense-code jump which then results in a reset.

Make sure that that event handler for key down is attached to a valid object; if you are using "stage" then make sure it exists.  When you move out of focus, the event handler may be left associated with a null object; when you reenter, it doesn't exist anymore, and therefore you get the reset behaviour.

This thread may help provide more detail: 
[Adding a key listener in Action Script 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481314/adding-a-key-listener-in-action-script-3)

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply. I looked through the link you gave me and i guess it has something to do with it. However, when i tie the "spin" function to another keycode the game works just fine when i go out of focus and back. The issue arises - as it seems - exclusivly when i tie a function to the space key (keyCode 32). I solved the issue by rebinding the key to "SHIFT". But still it would be great to know what's up with the SPACE key.
The game works fine with space if i use Internet Explorer. Other browers doesn't work with the space key. It's the same issue with all of them.